# I am working on videoview in android some specific videos are not working in video view

Tags: android, android-videoview, universal, android-video-player

Almost every videos are playing in my videoview but some specific URL are not playing every time in my videoview while they are perfectly working in system web browser and mobile webbrowser:

Here is my error code:

```
MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
11-22 16:28:15.269 15589-15609/com.videodemo E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
11-22 16:28:15.269 15589-15589/com.videodemo E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Comment: Can you post a link of a video that you claim is not working with videoview? That way others can investigate what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Here is the link : http://chilax.com/chilax_app/public/videos/3h4u5gios-video217112016.mp4

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check with this.:---

        // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
    // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask

    // Create a progressbar
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoViewActivity.this);
    // Set progressbar title
    pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Tutorial");
    // Set progressbar message
    pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // Show progressbar
    pDialog.show();

    try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                VideoViewActivity.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
        videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoview.setVideoURI(video);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    videoview.requestFocus();
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            videoview.start();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Still same error is showing :                                                                          11-22 08:45:10.227 14039-14055/com.videoplayertask E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
11-22 08:45:10.330 14039-14039/com.videoplayertask E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)

Answer (score 0):

```
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
            Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://your package name/" + R.raw.Your Video);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            videoview.requestFocus();
            videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
            {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
            videoview.start();
            }
            });
       `
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of investigating, i think the problem lies with your video codec format. Since android videoview does not support all kinds of codecs that are out there, it is very much possible that the video you are trying to play is not supported by android-sdk.

> Although android-sdk could've given a specific error so that we can
>   understand why the video is not playing.